# unreasonable netperf benchmark results

Tags: azure, networking, performance-testing, sles

I used netperf benchmark with the next commands:

server side:
netserver -4 -v -d -N -p

client side:
netperf -H  -p  -l 60 -T 1,1 -t TCP_RR

And I received the results:

MIGRATED TCP REQUEST/RESPONSE TEST from 0.0.0.0 (0.0.0.0) port 0 AF_INET to 10.0.0.28 () port 0 AF_INET : demo : first burst 0 : cpu bind

Local /Remote

Socket Size   Request  Resp.   Elapsed  Trans.
Send   Recv   Size     Size    Time     Rate
bytes  Bytes  bytes    bytes   secs.    per sec

16384  131072 1        1       60.00    9147.83
16384  131072

But when I changed the client to single CPU (same machine) by adding "maxcpus=1 nr_cpus=1" to kernel command line.
And I ran the next command:

netperf -H  -p  -l 60 -t TCP_RR

I received the next results:

MIGRATED TCP REQUEST/RESPONSE TEST from 0.0.0.0 (0.0.0.0) port 0 AF_INET to 10.0.0.28 () port 0 AF_INET : demo : first burst 0 : cpu bind

Local /Remote

Socket Size   Request  Resp.   Elapsed  Trans.
Send   Recv   Size     Size    Time     Rate
bytes  Bytes  bytes    bytes   secs.    per sec

16384  131072 1        1       60.00    10183.33
16384  131072

Q: I don't understand how the performance has been improved when I decreased the CPUs number from 64 to 1 CPU?

Some technique information: I used Standard_L64s_v3 instance type of Azure; OS: sles:15:sp2

Comment: Just for clarifying: the results are repeated at least 10 times. All the times single CPU is better than multi CPUs system.

Comment: When you say you get the same result ten times in a row, is that on the same instantiation of either the single or 64 vCPU system? Also, how are you switching between 1 and 64 vCPUs?  There can be any number of possibilities - with 64 vCPUs perhaps your workload is spanning NUMA nodes and it isn't with 1 vCPU.  Perhaps you get a higher hardware CPU frequency with just the one vCPU than with 64.

Comment: I meant that with single CPU the results are about 10GB per sec, and with 64 CPUs the results are about 9GB per sec.
for single CPU I added "maxcpus=1 nr_cpus=1" to kernel command line.

Comment: Hi @user1994587, if the provided answer resolved your issue, you may mark it as answer or upvote it so that others who encounter the similar issue, it may be useful for them or community members.

Answer (score 1):

•   The ‘netperf’ utility command executed by you on the client side is as follows and is the same after changing the number of CPUs on the client side but you can see an improvement in performance after decreasing the number of vCPUs on the client VM: -

```
netperf -H -p -l 60 -I 1,1 -t TCP_RR
```

The above command implies that you want to *test the network connectivity performance between the host ‘Server’ and ‘Client’ for TCP Request/Response and get the results in a default directory path where pipes will be created for a period of 60 seconds*.

•   The **CPU utilization measurement mechanism uses ‘proc/stat’ on Linux OS to record the time spent for such command executions**. The code for this mechanism can be found in **‘src/netcpu_procstat.c’**. Thus, you can check the configuration file accordingly.

Also, the **CPU utilization mechanism in a virtual guest environment, i.e., a virtual machine may not reflect the actual utilization as in a bare metal environment because much of the networking processing happens outside the context of the virtual machine**. Thus, as per the below documentation link by Hewlett-Packard: -

**https://hewlettpackard.github.io/netperf/doc/netperf.html**

> **If one is looking to measure the added overhead of a virtualization mechanism, rather than rely on CPU utilization, one can rely instead on netperf _RR tests - path-lengths and overheads can be a significant fraction of the latency, so increases in overhead should appear as decreases in transaction rate. Whatever you do, DO NOT rely on the throughput of a _STREAM test. Achieving link-rate can be done via a multitude of options that mask overhead rather than eliminate it.**

As a result, I would suggest **you rely on other monitoring tools available in Azure, i.e., Azure Monitor, Application insights, etc.**

Answer (score 1):

Looking more closely at your netperf command line:

netperf -H -p -l 60 -T 1,1 -t TCP_RR

The -H option expects to take a hostname as an argument.  And the -p option expects to take a port number as an argument.  As written the "-p" will be interpreted as a hostname.  And when I tried it at least will fail.  I assume you've omitted some of the command line?

The -T option will bind where netperf and netserver will run (in this case on vCPU 1 on the netperf side and vCPU 1 on the netserver side) but it will not necessarily control where at least some of the network stack processing will take place.  So, in your 64-vCPU setup, the interrupts for the networking traffic and perhaps the stack will run on a different vCPU.  In your 1-vCPU setup, everything will be on the one vCPU.  It is quite conceivable you are seeing the effects of cache-to-cache transfers in the 64-vCPU case leading to lower transaction/s rates.

Going to multi-processor will increase aggregate performance, but it will not necessarily increase single thread/stream performance.  And single thread/stream performance can indeed degrade.